# HttpURLConnection fails with 404 Error

Tags: java, http, url, http-status-code-404

My httpURLConnection fails with 404 - Resource not Found error. The same URL works on my firefox poster and returns 200/ok. Both the applications(webapp and the URL-app) are located on the same machine. I found from another thread that I need to add below 2 lines to make it work when the same URL works from browser-

urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");

Unfortunately adding above lines didn't fix the problem. Am I doing anything wrong in the code below ? Any useful suggestions will be much appreciated.

```
{

String computerName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();

url = new URL("http://"+computerName+":8080"+"/cerprovider/devices");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection",     "Keep-Alive");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(500);

        // Create I/O streams
        outStream = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        //inStream = new DataInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        // Send request
        outStream.writeBytes(<blah>.toString());
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();

        BufferedReader in = null;
        String responseErrorString = "";
        _tracer.info("Response code --"+urlConnection.getResponseCode());
        InputStream error = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
        _tracer.info("Error from the connection --"+error.toString());
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        for(int c = -1; (c = error.read()) != -1; )
            buf.append((char)c);
        responseErrorString = new String (buf);
        _tracer.info("responseErrorString--"+responseErrorString);

}
```

Comment: What kind of request are you trying to do - POST, GET, etc.?  and what is your request payload?  Keep in mind that if you paste a URL into a browser directly you are doing a simple GET with no form data, and it looks like your code is trying to do a lot more than that.

Comment: I am doing a "POST" and I am trying my post request with content-type as text/plain on the firefox poster tool.It goes through fine and returns 200/ok. My request data is a comma-separated simple string.

Answer (score -2):

try to send request again. In my project I am using Apache HttpClient to send request & many times the 404 error resolve by sending request again. (but not all the time)

Also use httpfox plugin on firefox to check what exactly happening when u send request.

404 error is supposed to b for 'resource temporarily not available'.

Comment: also why you put this line :         urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(Integer.MAX_VALUE));  is this required?

Comment: I resolved this. For some reason my code didn't like -   urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*"); Changing this to accept text/plain fixed the problem